# Workday integration jobs failing

Tags: workday-api

We run integration jobs between Workday and on premise applications. The integration 
jobs run and dump or get data files on a sftp server, on our site, running bitvise sftp server.
The integrations connect to our sftp server through a virtual account and public keys.
These jobs have been running fine until a couple of days ago when some of the integrations
started to fail; the connections to the sftp server seems to be successful at first, but they get termininated right away. We'll appreciate any help with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed after UTM (Threat management) on Palo was disabled.
Here is Network Admin:

"The solution was to remove IPS/IDS check from the rule that allow Workday servers to sftp in.

My guess is after Palo Alto’s dynamic updates(Antivirus/Wildfire) it started to cut the working session all of a sudden."